# Generate XYZ Tiles (MBTiles) tool results in error

Tags: qgis, mbtiles

My first time generating MBTiles results in an error.  I'm using QGIS 3.28.4 with the **Generate XYZ Tiles (MBTiles)** tool.  I've tried a variety of tool options, but all result in the same error statement.

I have two layers loaded:

- A point Geopackage layer (EPSG: 2927)
- Google Terrain basemap, loaded from the Browser panel via XYZ Tiles

Here's the error output:

```
QGIS version: 3.28.4-Firenze  
QGIS code revision: fd0fb72ab3  
Qt version: 5.15.3  
Python version: 3.9.5  
GDAL version: 3.6.2  
GEOS version: 3.11.1-CAPI-1.17.1  
PROJ version: Rel. 9.1.1, December 1st, 2022  
PDAL version: 2.4.3 (git-version: f8d673)  
Algorithm started at: 2023-03-24T10:20:15  
Algorithm 'Generate XYZ tiles (MBTiles)' starting…  
Input parameters:  
{ 'BACKGROUND_COLOR' : QColor(0, 0, 0, 0), 'DPI' : 96, 'EXTENT' :  '1665435.123700000,2029392.838200000,803710.923600000,1040216.779200000 [EPSG:2927]', 'METATILESIZE' : 4, 'OUTPUT_FILE' : 'C:/AAA/PROJECTS/AUDUBON_NCW/KESTREL_BOXES/MERGIN/2023/test_1.mbtiles', 'QUALITY' : 75, 'TILE_FORMAT' : 1, 'ZOOM_MAX' : 14, 'ZOOM_MIN' : 10 }

Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py", line 463, in processAlgorithm
self.generate(writer, parameters, context, feedback)  
File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py", line 308, in generate
writer.set_parameters(tile_params)  
File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TilesXYZ.py", line 360, in set_parameters  
ds = driver.Create(self.filename, 1, 1, 1, options=['TILE_FORMAT=%s' % tile_format] + options)  
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Create'

Execution failed after 0.04 seconds

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Generate XYZ tiles (MBTiles)' finished
```

I'm guessing that the problem lies within the error statement *'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Create'*.  I've searched for that phrase on Stack Overflow, but my Python skills are not up to the task.

Suggestions?

**Edit:**

Based on the kind comment by Houska, I tried the following, both without success:

1. Conducted an advanced osgwo4w install, searching for any package meeting the search term *mbt*.  Unfortunately, nothing was returned, leading me to understand that there are no supplementary MBTiles-related drivers available.
2. Downloaded the standalone version of 3.28.4 and tried the **Generate XYZ Tiles (MBTiles)** tool.  Again, the same error was thrown.

**Edit 2:**

My responses to Houska's second and third comments:

1. Yes, I am able to view MBTiles
2. Submitting *gdal_translate --format* to the Windows Command Processor window is successful; numerous options appear. (Houska suggested that I use *"...a terminal from QGIS..."*, but I don't what that is...)
3. The originally-reported error still occurs when I use the **Generate XYZ Tiles (MBTiles)** tool in QGIS 3.30 (GDAL 3.6.3)

Comment: I strongly suspect the problem comes from the previous line to the `driver.Create` invocation, which is probably `driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('MBTiles')` (my installed version is off by 1 in line numbers). For some reason, gdal does not have the MBTiles driver installed for you. That line therefore does not return a driver as expected, and so `driver` is an invalid `None`. As to why you don't have an MBTiles driver, I don't know.

Comment: Weird. Things to try:
1. Try opening an MBTiles to read from within QGIS (to check if the installed GDAL has the MBTiles driver)
2. Open a terminal from QGIS and run `gdal_translate --format MBTiles` to check if GDAL is recognizing the MBTILES driver standalone (does it return tons of options or an error)
3. Try installing and running QGIS 3.30 instead of 3.28.4 - I have 3.30 which has GDAL 3.6.3, which does have MBTiles working (didn't try Generate XYZ Tiles though)...find it strange you have 3.6.2

Comment: Just tried QGIS 3.30 (OSGeo4Win) with gdal 3.6.3, had no such error, all fine.